# Powershell disk space script

Tags: powershell, alert, diskspace

[I have a powershell script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/6e935887-6b30-4654-b977-6f5d289f3a63#content). In short, the script can collect disk space info from multiple servers and put that in a .htm report that can be sent by mail.

Now, the script does collect the disk info into a report, but i would like it to send an email only if one of the disks has free space lower than the critical value defined in the script.

The script:

```
# First lets create a text file, where we will later save the freedisk space info 
$freeSpaceFileName = "c:\disk_space.htm" 
$serverlist = "c:\sl.txt" 
$warning = 50 
$critical = 10 
New-Item $freeSpaceFileName -ItemType file -Force 
# Getting the freespace info using WMI 
#Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk  | Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} | format-table DeviceID, VolumeName,status,Size,FreeSpace | Out-File "C:\temp\FreeSpace.txt 
# Function to write the HTML Header to the file 
Function writeHtmlHeader 
{ 
param($fileName) 
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm') 
Add-Content $fileName "<html>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<head>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>" 
Add-Content $fileName '<title>Disk Report</title>' 
add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">' 
add-content $fileName  "<!--" 
add-content $fileName  "td {" 
add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;" 
add-content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "}" 
add-content $fileName  "body {" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;" 
add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;" 
add-content $fileName  "" 
add-content $fileName  "table {" 
add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;" 
add-content $fileName  "}" 
add-content $fileName  "-->" 
add-content $fileName  "</style>" 
Add-Content $fileName "</head>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<body>" 

add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%'>" 
add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>" 
add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>" 
add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>Disk Report - $date</strong></font>" 
add-content $fileName  "</td>" 
add-content $fileName  "</tr>" 
add-content $fileName  "</table>" 

} 

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file 
Function writeTableHeader 
{ 
param($fileName) 

Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Drive</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>Drive Label</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Freespace %</td>" 
Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
} 

Function writeHtmlFooter 
{ 
param($fileName) 

Add-Content $fileName "</body>" 
Add-Content $fileName "</html>" 
} 

Function writeDiskInfo 
{ 
param($fileName,$devId,$volName,$frSpace,$totSpace) 
$totSpace=[math]::Round(($totSpace/1073741824),2) 
$frSpace=[Math]::Round(($frSpace/1073741824),2) 
$usedSpace = $totSpace - $frspace 
$usedSpace=[Math]::Round($usedSpace,2) 
$freePercent = ($frspace/$totSpace)*100 
$freePercent = [Math]::Round($freePercent,0) 
 if ($freePercent -gt $warning) 
 { 
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#32B232' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
 } 
 elseif ($freePercent -le $critical) 
 { 
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#FF0000' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 Add-Content $fileName "<tr>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>" 
 Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#E1E100' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
 Add-Content $fileName "</tr>" 
 } 
} 
Function sendEmail 
{ param($from,$to,$subject,$smtphost,$htmlFileName) 
$body = Get-Content $htmlFileName 
$smtp= New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient $smtphost 
$msg = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $from, $to, $subject, $body 
$msg.isBodyhtml = $true 
$smtp.send($msg) 

} 

writeHtmlHeader $freeSpaceFileName 
foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist) 
{ 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server </strong></font></td>" 
 Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</tr>" 

 writeTableHeader $freeSpaceFileName 

 $dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} 
 foreach ($item in $dp) 
 { 
 Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 
 writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 

 } 
} 
writeHtmlFooter $freeSpaceFileName 
$date = ( get-date ).ToString('dd.MM.yyyy') 

#sendEmail cdarwin@evolve.com cdarwin@evolve.com "Disk Space Report - $Date" hub1 $freeSpaceFileName
```

I already tried to add some kind of IF, but it didn't work,

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show us what you tried. In what way did it "not work"? Have you spent time reading & understanding the script? How is your "threshold" defined? MB, GB, percentage, other? I see at least three changes that can be made to it (it's written for PowerShell v1, so it's quite old) that will improve speed and reduce complexity (including one which would solve your filtering problem at the same time).

Comment: The more I read this script, the less I like it. It "works" but ignores a lot of PowerShell conventions and best practices.

Comment: I wanted a script just to avoid installing additional software on my servers. Just to say i'm not knowledgeable in powershell. I added this: `if ($freePercent -le $critical)
{send-mailmessage -To email@domain.com -subject 'Disk Space Report' -from server@domain.com -SmtpServer mail.domain.com -attachment $freeSpaceFileName
}`. I kinda dont like the script myself but it does what i need. Threshold is percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a few lines of code that will check for a threshold, and send an e-mail only if the threshold is exceeded.

```
$Threshold = 10GB; ########### Add this line
$ThresholdExceeded = $false; ############## Add this line

foreach ($server in Get-Content $serverlist) 
{ 
    Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>" 
    Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>" 
    Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server </strong></font></td>" 
    Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</tr>" 

    writeTableHeader $freeSpaceFileName 

    $dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3} 
    foreach ($item in $dp) 
    {
        ################ Add this next line
        if ($Item.FreeSpace -lt $Threshold) { $ThresholdExceeded = $true; };             Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 
        writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size 

    } 
}

################### Add this code
if ($ThresholdExceeded) {
    sendEmail cdarwin@evolve.com cdarwin@evolve.com "Disk Space Report - $Date" hub1 $freeSpaceFileName;
}
```

Comment: Hi again. This new code works, but i was wondering would it be too hard to make the threshold $freepercent instead of $Item.FreeSpace? That was my original idea of the script in the first place. I tried doing this: `if ($freePercent -lt $critical) { $ThresholdExceeded = $true }` but the script then sends an email every time it runs. Which i don't need it to do. Thx again for the help.